# Replace commas between at's on notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a CSV with data to import, the separator character is the comma here; but when the row or line has two e-mails, a comma separates them so the import fails at that point.
So I thought removing the commas between two at's when they're on the same line, but I don't know how.
If you have an alternative solucion, it'll be welcome too!!
Thanks.

Example:

```
ENTERPRISE1 S.L.,,ENTERPRISE1,999461678,,,,,,ent1@mail.com, ent1alternate@mail2.com,Spain,,,
ENTERPRISE2 S.A.,,ENTERPRISE2.,999859177,,,,,,ent2@mail.com,Italy,,,
```

Comment: I haven’t used notepad++ so I don’t how to write macro for it (if it is possible). But simple pseudo-code would be following: 
1- get how many @ at the current line,
2- if more than one @ exists, get the comma and @ positions,
3- first @ position > comma position between 2 adjacent emails > last @ position

Comment: If it is possible, it will be better to change the way the file is build. Change the comma that delimites the mails with another character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data doesn't use any escaping and the @-char will only be present in the mail column, you could use `((?:@|\G(?!^))[^,]+),([^,@]+@)` as a search pattern and `$1$2` for replace. This will also handle more than two mails in the column correctly. of course you can place a separator of choice between `$1` and `$2`, like `$1;$2`

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/fH9vI8/1).

Comment: @Destrif I really don't see the error - what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with notepad:

search field:

```
([^@]+@[^,]+)\s*,\s*([^@]+@[^,]+)
```

Replace field:

```
\1|\2
```

Check regular expression checkbox

So

```
ent1@mail.com, ent1alternate@mail2.com
```

will be:

```
ent1@mail.com|ent1alternate@mail2.com
```

This will let you keep your column organization, and allow to process data and avoid any lost

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use to use the correct CSV formatting: double quotes around any field that contains the delimiter.

```
([^,]+@[^,]+,[^,]+@[^,]+)
```

Replace:

```
"\1"
```

(Regex adapted from [destrif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37807129/1919238)).

Answer (score -1):

Looks like in your example you always have a empty space after the comma separating multiple email addresses.
If that's a generic rule, you should replace the ", " (comma + empty space) string by another separator like semicolon, using the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to call the replace function.

Comment: I didn't. I just edited in the review. All votes are anonymous, so no one can tell who voted which way - even the moderators can't.